# Recommended books for process engineering?

Tags: chemical-engineering, process-engineering, compressed-gases

I made a career change from machine design to CNG processing. What I’m looking for are some good books/handbooks that cover the following topics. Something similar to Machinery’s Handbook.

- Piping, flanges and welding (for gas). E.g. pipe dimensions, pressure ratings, losses, metallurgy etc.
- Heat exchangers (tube & shell)
- Boilers
- PLC controls

Thanks!

Comment: Heat Transfer by Siminson can be handy.

Comment: This looks like a [resource-hunting question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/1832). Such questions are prone to becoming out-dated, and are therefore considered off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 1):

First get the newest edition of *Perry's Chemical Engineers' Handbook* a.k.a *The Chemical Engineer's Bible* which covers at the very least the basics of pretty much everything you need.

Then look at *Coulson & Richardson's Chemical Engineering* series and pick up the volumes you need.  Pretty much everyone has used at least Volume 6 (Design) now and then. Other volumes cover specific areas, so you may not need them all.